# Google Cloud Function giving

Tags: cloud, zip, bytesio

Trying to download covid data in google cloud function. **This code runs in Jupyter notebook successfully.** I need to save the zip file in memory and then I later on do pandas manipulations with it.

But, I am getting the error: Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Details: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/user_code/Weekly_Data_Counts.csv'

I have looked through other posts where defining /tmp/ is the solution. Don't think its applicable here.
Any idea what to do?

Code below:

def covid_data_fetch_2(self, request):

```
#Download Data
print('Retrieving web page')
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
zip_file_url = 'https://gis.cdc.gov/grasp/covid19_5_api/PostPhase05DataDownload'
data = {"AppVersion":"Public","DatasourcesDT":[{"ID":1,"Name":"Weekly_Data_Counts"},{"ID":4,"Name":"Weekly_Data_Percent"},{"ID":3,"Name":"Medical_Conditions"},{"ID":2,"Name":"Characteristics"}],"VirusesDT":[{"ID":1,"Name":"1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"2"},{"ID":3,"Name":"3"},{"ID":4,"Name":"4"},{"ID":5,"Name":"5"}],"SeasonsDT":[{"ID":59,"Name":"59"}],"CategoryDT":[],"ConditionDT":[{"ID":1,"Name":"1"},{"ID":13,"Name":"13"},{"ID":2,"Name":"2"},{"ID":3,"Name":"3"},{"ID":12,"Name":"12"},{"ID":14,"Name":"14"},{"ID":4,"Name":"4"},{"ID":5,"Name":"5"},{"ID":6,"Name":"6"},{"ID":9,"Name":"9"},{"ID":10,"Name":"10"},{"ID":11,"Name":"11"},{"ID":15,"Name":"15"},{"ID":16,"Name":"16"}],"CasetypeDT":[{"ID":1,"Name":"1"},{"ID":2,"Name":"2"},{"ID":3,"Name":"3"}],"FileType":"zip"}
r = requests.post(zip_file_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
zf.extractall()
```

Comment: Did you copy over the /user_code/Weekly_Data_Counts.csv file locally and point to this path?

Comment: No I did not copy it locally. I may be confused by your question. I'm trying to store it in memory.

Comment: solved by adding '/tmp/' to the extractall function